# Substitution in vimscript failing

Tags: vim

I'm missing something subtle and silly on this.  I have a short vim script.  In it, I'm trying to do:

```
s/.*_____.*/\=repeat('=', 78)/
```

(That's the exact code.)

When I do `/\v.*____.*` in normal mode, I can successfully find the pattern (more than once).  When I do that substition in normal mode, it succeeds.

I'm sure I'm missing something as far as escaping a character somewhere.  Please enlighten me!

Comment: Are you aware that your substitution only covers the current line; you need to use `%s...` to apply it to the entire buffer (or apply your function to all lines individually).

Comment: OMG... I'm an idiot.  No, completely missed that I somehow dropped the %.  Would you like to Answer with that so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome, that can happen. Glad I could help. I've added an answer with some more background information in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `s/` command only covers the current line; this is not what you usually want.

The simplest approach is to use `%s/...` to process the entire buffer. However, your mapping / command may want to support arbitrary ranges. For that, `:call` will usually invoke your user-defined function once for each line, unless you define the function that it handles the range itself. See `:help function-range-example` for details.